# EclipseLink doesn't include generate options on a ManyToMany relationship

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jpa, eclipselink

I'm having some issues with ***EclipseLink / JPA*** (2.5.2), ***Postgresql*** (9.3) and the ***schema generation***. For my Spring application, I would love to create a ***@ManyToMany*** relationship between two classes, but it refuses to create the third middle table supplied with two *cascade options*.

Both my classes have the proper implementations of *hashCode()* and *equals(...)* and both are involved in other relationships, ***non @ManyToMany*** of course, that support ***CASCADE*** options and work fine.

```
[Stream]-(0..n)--<streams_tags>--(0..n)-[Tag]
```

The following is a fragment of my DDL script regarding the ManyToMany relationship:

```
CREATE TABLE streams_tags (tagged_streams INTEGER NOT NULL, tags INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (tagged_streams, tags))
...
ALTER TABLE streams_tags ADD CONSTRAINT UNQ_streams_tags_0 UNIQUE (tags, tagged_streams)
...
ALTER TABLE streams_tags ADD CONSTRAINT FK_streams_tags_tagged_streams FOREIGN KEY (tagged_streams) REFERENCES TAGS (TID)
...
ALTER TABLE streams_tags ADD CONSTRAINT FK_streams_tags_tags FOREIGN KEY (tags) REFERENCES STREAMS (SID)
```

The following stubs are extracted straight from the involved classes, *Stream* and *Tag*:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = Stream.TAGS_JOIN_TABLE, 
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = Stream.TAGS_JOIN_COLUMN), 
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = Tag.TAGGED_STREAMS_JOIN_COLUMN), 
            uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {
        Stream.TAGS_JOIN_COLUMN, Tag.TAGGED_STREAMS_JOIN_COLUMN }))
@CascadeOnDelete
List<Tag> tags;
```

The following is the *Tag* class, which doesn't hold directly the relationship.

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags")  
List<Stream> streams;
```

And this is the predictable error that I received when I try to delete a tagged ***Stream***:

```
ERROR: update or delete on table "streams" violates foreign key constraint "fk_streams_tags_tags" on table "streams_tags"
  Dettaglio: Key (sid)=(2) is still referenced from table "streams_tags".
```

Thank you in advance, any help will be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using @CascadeOnDelete which tells EclipseLink that the database will handle deleting streams_tags references, as described here:  http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/a_cascadeondelete.htm

Either remove this annotation so that EclipseLink will remove from the join table, or change the DDL so that ON DELETE CASCADE is included or just let EclipseLink generate the DDL for you http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/DDL or through JPA using http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Release/2.5/JPA21#DDL_generation

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I completely misunderstood the difference between _@CascadeOnDelete_ and the _cascade={}_ option. I solved removing the @CascadeOnDelete and adding explicitly any new tag to the stream's collection, is this the correct way?

Comment: Yes, the relationship needs to be maintained on both sides in most cases to keep the cache in synch with the database, otherwise it won't show up until the entities are refreshed/reloaded